# Can't upload photo to googleDrive from ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I followed the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart
i register my app, got secret key and put it in the appication, getting some token here: 
      func viewController(vc : UIViewController,
                      finishedWithAuth authResult : GTMOAuth2Authentication, error : NSError?) {

```
if let error = error {
  service.authorizer = nil
  showAlert("Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
  return
}
service.authorizer = authResult
```

It's fine. But when i tried to upload photo to google disc - i got this error:
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}]},"id":"gtl_1"}
2016-04-23 14:21:06.329 PROJECT_NAME[560:210039] Premature failure: upload-status:"final"  location:(null)

Here is the code. Can someone tell me what i m doing wrong?

```
func uploadPhoto(image: UIImage) {
  let name = "Photo"
  let content = image
  let mineType = "image/jpeg"

  let metadata = GTLDriveFile()
  metadata.name = name

  guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(content) else {
    return
  }
  let uploadParameters = GTLUploadParameters(data: data, MIMEType: mineType)
  let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesCreateWithObject(metadata,    uploadParameters: uploadParameters) as GTLQueryDrive
  service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, updatedFile, error) in
    print(ticket)
    if error != nil {
      print(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem was found - should auth with another scope for this. Didn't get it from tutorial)

Comment: What do you mean? I am facing same problem. How can I enable auth?

Comment: @WasimSafdar, Hello!
I mean that GoogleDrive have diffferentes scopes with their own access level. You can see them in GTLDriveConstants.m 
I used this one to write files to GoodleDrive
    private let scopes = [kGTLAuthScopeDrive]